# Slow Query Performance

Tags: oledb, sql-server-ce-4

I am running some very large databases (500 MB and 300 MB) in my application on several different machines.

From a hardware perspective, the machines have been identically configured.

I am using SQL Server CE 4.0 as my DBMS.

The performance critical query has been indexed to improve its performance.

The problem is that on [only] one of the machines, I am observing egregiously slow query performance.  This usually happens after a long period of time of inactivity (from a query perspective).  After I do several (about 7-8) queries, the slow performance disappears.

The weird thing is that this initial slow query performance does not happen on the other machine.

The only difference between the two machines is the data contained inside the databases.

I suspect that the distribution of data on the slow machine is somehow reducing the effectiveness of the indexing and that SQL Server CE has to rebalance the indexing in a much more significant way than on the other faster machine.

One thing I notice is that when the query is very slow, the disk activity increases significantly and the process corresponding to reading the database shows a spike in the read bytes.

This does not happen on the other machine.

Does anyone know how I might go about root causing this issue?

My code is written in C++ and uses the ATL/OLEDB API to manipulate the database.

UPDATE: My performance profiling activities indicate that it's not the query itself that is slow - it is the processing of the returned rowset that takes a while.  For each row returned, I query another database for related data.  I understand that this is not the right way to do it but the performance problem only happens on one machine.  One thing I noticed is that when I have other unrelated queries happening on the same database in other threads, the unrelated queries will stall the query that is exhibiting the performance problem.

Comment: Just FYI, CE is deprecated. You should consider using Express or LocalDB.

Comment: That's the plan - but that can't be done in 1 day.  We've got angry customers wanting this problem fixed yesterday.